# Need help adding multiple guard statements to check character count

Tags: swift, function, option-type

I'm starting a 12 week program for iOS dev on the 27th. I've been going through this Swift Dev book that I bought on Amazon until I start. I'm currently at Functions. I need a little help with the "Bronze" challenge if you would be so kind.

This is the question:

"Like if/ else conditions, guard statements support the use of multiple clauses to perform additional checks. Using additional clauses with a guard statement gives you further control over the statement’s condition. Refactor the greetByMiddleName( name:) function to have an additional clause in its guard statement. This clause should check to see if the middle name is less than four characters long. If it is, then greet that person by their middle name. If it is not, then use the generic greeting."

This is the code:

```
func greetByMiddleName(fromFullName name: (first: String, middle: String?, last: String)) {


        guard
        let middleName = name.middle
        else { print(" Hey there!")
        return
    }
    print(" Hey \( middleName)") }
greetByMiddleName( fromFullName: ("Dexter","Yakuza"," Morgan"))
```

I was trying to use dot notation to check against the object but that's definitely not working. I'd appreciate any help that I can get at solving this.

What I was trying:

`let middleNameCount = middleName.characters.count` <- something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

A condition on the `guard` statement would look like this:

```
guard let middleName = name.middle, middleName.characters.count < 4 else {
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how you want to use it - whether the condition should be < 4 or >= 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

On Swift 4 "character" has been deprecated so the guard statement should be as follow:

guard let middleName = name.middle, middleName.count > 4 else {